# Adding class inside AJAX .done function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote small script to adding class where .done function is called, but this solution doesn't work.

```js
$("#test").on("click", function() {

  var test = "foo bar";

  $.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {
      test: test
    }
  }).done(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().addClass("success");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" id="test">click me</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: where exactly you wanna add the class?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: yes - why not just give the table-tag, I presume, and id and then find it instead of `parent().parent()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` inside the callback is not the same outside it refers to the `jqXHR` object of the ajax request not the element that the event handler was bound to, you should save it first outside, then use it as variable like :

```
$("#test").on("click", function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  var test = "foo bar";

  $.post({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: {
      test: test
    }
  }).done(function() {
    _this.parent().parent().addClass("success");
  });

});
```

Comment: not defined _this in answer

Comment: we also can do a .bind(this) right to done callback

Comment: No need for bind in this case for the proper way...

Comment: bind also work right

Comment: Yes should work..

Answer (score 0):

Here is way to use `this` inside Ajax call. First store Node inside that variable and use `that` variable instead of this. I m using `GET` request for example , but it will work on `POST` request as well.

```js
$("#test").on("click",function(){
       var that = $(this);
        var postData ={};
        $.ajax({
       type:"GET",
       url: "https://ipinfo.io/json",//your url
          data:postData,
          success: function (msg) {
                   
             },
          error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
     console.log("error occured  : " +thrownError)
           } 
        }).done(function() {
    $(that).parent().parent().addClass("success");
  });;
})
```

```css
.success{
background-color : #fc0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#" id="test">click me</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```